# circular dependency

Tags: c#, code-organization, circular-dependency

I have 2 projects

- *UI*: contains all my forms and user control
- *Translation*: contains my translation code used to translate the UI

The Ui project obviously needs a reference to the *translation* project since it needs translation.

Since I defined custom user controls in the UI that need special translation. The Translation project needs to know the type and thus *translation* also needs a reference to *UI* resulting in a circular dependency.

is this actually a problem and yes how do I solve this best? Do I take out the custom types and put them in a seperate project?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following good practice, and especially [sepatation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), your translation library should know nothing about *what* it is translating, only that it needs to translate text a into b.

Typically this is done with a methods or methods which  take an identifier for a string, and a culture to translate to.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var tranlated = MyTranslator.Translate("HelloWorldMessage",ci);
```